# UML Class Diagram Resources

Tags: java, oop, resources, uml, class-design

Does anyone have any good resources for refining my skills in developing class diagrams? Would like any strong tutorials in UML 2.0 ideally, but searches seem to be returning poor results.

Also currently revising for a final year exam and really want to try and get my teeth into a practice paper with a model answer, I've searched high and low without any luck, does anyone happen to have any suggestions on where i might find some?

Basically any resources to help push my revision along. Would relish the chance to look at more advance stuff and push the boundaries.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks,
Ricky

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Online UML Guide from StackOverFlow (No more available)
- [Practical UML: A Hands-On Introduction for Developers](http://dn.codegear.com/article/31863)
- Unified Modeling Language (UML) Tutorial (No more available)
- [UML Tutorial and Introduction](http://www.cragsystems.co.uk/ITMUML/)

Answer (score 2):

[Martin Fowler Wrote a book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321193687).  The latest edition was published for UML2...

Answer (score 1):

Sparx Systems has a UML tutor here: http://www.sparxsystems.com/uml-tutorial.html

They also have a trial version of their tools, if you are so inclined...

EDIT: Be sure to check their navigation pane for additional resources as well.

Answer (score 1):

I always keep a few cheat sheets in my bookmarks for quick reference.

Try these:

- http://loufranco.com/blog/assets/cheatsheet.pdf
- http://www.scribd.com/doc/399157/UML-20-Cheatsheet

Comment: The second link is good.

Answer (score 0):

A collection of UML resources online (Not availabe anymore)
A collection of [UML cheat sheets](http://modeling-languages.com/blog/content/top-seven-uml-cheatsheets)